# Choosing a World's/Region's/etc. Interest Rates

Tags: science-based, economy, finances

In several RPG campaigns, I've seen player characters try to either make investments or borrow significant amounts of money. This made me wonder: which sorts of worlds should have interest rates that significantly differ from the ranges found on modern Terra?

For example: Should the moneylenders of stereotypical fantasy worlds with their [MedievalStasis](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MedievalStasis) ask for a temporary use of their money? How about setting with galaxy-spanning, millennia-old republics, like Star Wars - should their rates be low because the economy seems to be rather stable? How about the opposite extreme of fast-paced cyberpunk and transhumanist settings with the singularity right behind the corner - should their rates be high because the world is changing and growing fast, and if so, how high (tens, hundreds etc.)?

Which world details should I keep in mind when deciding on how expensive it is usually to borrow money and how profitable is it to invest it, and how do those details influence the number? How much should it vary by region/polity/etc.?

I'm not expecting the things learned from answers to enable me to figure out highly precise and 100% reliable numbers. But learning at least about the likely trends and orders of magnitude would be nice.

Comment: you are asking for an advanced class in economics. I suspect this is too broad.

Comment: Well, obviously I'm not expecting the things learned from answers to enable me to figure out highly precise and 100% reliable numbers. But learning at least about the likely trends and orders of magnitude would be nice.

Comment: I also think it's too broad. The biggest problem is that it's also story dependant. During an economic boom, the interest rates would be low, during a recession - high. And that's not something you can really know. Further, these could be region and culture related. Maybe banks in one area just don't have loans, so you have to go to individuals. Perhaps loans are outlawed (for some reason), so you are left with only criminals "helping out a friend" where the interest might include taking the property of the lendee. In a cyberpunk setting, I'd expect seedy loan sharks to collect limbs. Etc.

Comment: *"Which sorts of worlds should have interest rates that significantly differ from the ranges found on modern Terra?"* Do you have any idea what is the range of interest rates found on modern Terra? Hint: as of  August 2019, the short-term interest rate of National Bank of Japan is -0.1% (that's *minus* one tenth of a percent, they will *pay you* to borrow money from them); the short-term interest rate of the National Bank of Turkey is 24.6%. And this excludes basket-case economies such as Zimbabwe.

Comment: The question I have is how do you get the Star Wars Universe is relatively stable, as a whole? It really isn't that place is a warzone. Sure there would be stable pockets but as a whole it's nuts.

Comment: @JCrosby Well, it seems like most of its planets have been settled for millennia, over those millennia life as depicted seems to be largely the same, the tech progress seems absent, the society seems pretty similar, droids didn't make humans obsolete etc. Star Wars seems to have the pseudo-futuristic equivalent of the aforementioned MedievalStasis.

Answer (score 5):

**The main factor is plausibility to the audience**

Since the risk of non-repayment by an adventurer seems rather high, the interest rate should be correspondingly high. For D&D, 20%-50% tends to work well.

In most adventuring and storytelling, interest rates are determined simply by what the adventurers are willing to pay *in that town* or on that particular planet. The next town (or planet) might have quite different rates - who is going to slog through 25 miles of Steamy Leech Marsh (and back) to compare rates? In macroeconomic terms, this is a *high-friction* environment.

The only world detail that matters is the handwave that explains why it's a high-friction environment -- why the Big Banks from Capital City haven't displaced the local moneylender...or why they left. Could be a collapse, corrupt local regulators, plague, etc.

"What the adventurers are willing to pay" is, of course, determined by the culture of the *audience*. You need a number that is reasonable to the audience, and merely *seems* consistent within the world. This is why 20%-50% is plausible *to us*. It's higher than most folks pay in our world, but the numbers are still conceptually graspable. It's high, but not too high...for the audience to accept.

There are two ways to keep it simple, understandable for the audience...

1. **Defined installments** of regular payments. This is useful for trustworthy adventurers who regularly return to the same place during a campaign. Fudge the interest rate to make nice, round payments.

   *"I'll lend you 3000 quatloos now. You pay me seven payments of 700 quatloos, one payment every six months."* (That's a bit over 20% APY [annual interest])
2. **Balloon payments**, where the adventurer is expected to pay back the entire loan at once after a windfall. This is useful for wanderers and shiftless heroes. Fudge the interest rate to make the payback super-easy to calculate.

   *"I'll lend you 3000 quatloos. You pay me interest of 2 quatloos per day. When you return with the Dragon's Hoard, drop by and pay me back out of one of the smaller chests of gold..."* (That's about 25% APY)

...and there are two ways to make it more complicated, if the story requires it.

1. **Collateral**: If the adventurer leaves some item of value as *security* with the moneylender, the rate can be lower.

   *"If you leave the Psychic Stone of Arundel in my vault, so I have something if you never return, then I'll lower the rate to one quatloo per day"* (about 12% APY)
2. **Equity**: Optionally, the moneylender becomes a *partner* in the expedition and gets a *share* of the reward instead of mere interest. Unlikely to journey (somebody must guard the strong room!). The other adventurers must acknowledge the moneylender's role, and the moneylender's right to their share. There are advantages to having a good business manager outfitting the expedition.

   *"I will personally pay for all the armor and weapons and supplies and donkeys. And your trips to the Tavern and Bordello. You leave Friday. I'm sending Carlos with you to mind the donkeys (not to fight). When you return, I get the equipment back...plus 25% of the Dragon's Hoard."*

Comment: The question is what the interest rates should *approximately* be depending on commonly-relevant setting parameters, such as the fast life of cyberpunk and transhumanist settings, or the stasis/stability of some fantasy and retrotech settings, not *whether* moneylenders would charge an interest. This answer seems to instead grab some base assumption and be calculating different repayment forms around it.

Comment: @vicky_molokh edited. Take a look now.

Comment: Religion may play a part as well. See Roman Catholicism and usury rules in Medieval and Renaissance periods. But yes, the higher the risk for the lender, the higher the interest. See also payday loans that can be 300+% in the real world vs. credit card rates in the 20-30% range vs. car loans in the 4-6% vs. mortgages of 3-7%....

Comment: "*"I'll lend you 3000 quatloos now. You pay me seven payments of 700 quatloos, one payment every six months." (That's a bit over 20% interest)*" that money lender is ripping you off - 7 times * 700 a payment is 4900 in total. That's not *a bit* over 20%, that is *a lot* over 20% - namely, it's 63%.

Comment: I'll also add that there is another way to make it complicated - usurers. Or people who try to *almost*, if not *completely* illegally rip people off from giving them loans. What usually happens is they either take a collateral if the lendee fails to give the money back. Then the lender makes sure the heroes fails to do so. Sending thugs works but it's even easier to just hide. So, according to the contract the payment should be done on Thursday but the lender is nowhere to be found. On Friday he can take the collateral with the contract as justification.

Comment: @VLAZ - Try the calculation again using interest per year (APY) which is what bookkeepers and banks and moneylenders actually use, not whole-term interest (which has no useful meaning since 'term' may be of variable length), Theft-of-collateral isn't really about lending - it's about theft, and tends to be a bad idea against steel-thewed heroes with a band of veteran, resourceful, ass-kicking adventurers at their back.

Comment: @user535733 but a good early level "villain" for a starting group of adventurers. Somebody funds their first expedition and then takes something valuable for the group. E.g., they had some shared house or maybe something smaller. Now the adventurers have to get it back but the city watch and government officials don't take kindly to people dissolving contracts using swords and axes. It can be a good early level plot hook if the group prefers more than just killing monsters. Or they might just get to work killing monsters to buy the collateral back.

Comment: @VLAZ true, and interesting...but seems irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @user535733 hence why I posted it as a comment about extra complications in the name of *story*

Answer (score 2):

Moneylending is an ancient practice to turning static piles of cash into larger piles of cash. Here are some general trends for moneylending that have a relationship with the amount of money being lent and the interest rates.

I will now point out that the kind of moneylending which is large sums of money at absurdly high rates isn't proper moneylending, it's thin-veiled extortion. It's only moneylending proper if your intended method of collecting the money is your client *giving* it to you, rather than you and your thugs beating them to a paste after harvesting their organs and stealing all their worldly possessions.

**Risk** - pretty basic. If your party are well respected adventurers, and you have a history of successful quests, asking a moneylender for a few thousand gold to finance an expedition at low interest is possible. On the flip side, the new kids of the block will be lucky to get a hundred gold.

**Competition** - standard economic fair. If there are multiple moneylenders, the rates are lowered, if there are only a handful, the rates go up. This is kind of what happened in the Middle Ages Europe.

**Borrowed** - Large amount have a bit lower interest rates for experienced guilds. On the flip side, if you're a risk, the more you borrow, the higher the interest will be, concept being that if you default, the other people that money were loaned to will make up the slack.

**Security** - Interest rates will drop if you can offer an object of equal value to your loan. I mean, it's kind of more pawning at this point, but moneylenders will generally accept objects of high value that can liquidated easily, i.e land, gold, gems, etc.

So, for instance, a brand new party in a large town with lots of moneylenders should be able to secure a small loan at a relatively competitive rate, say 25% over four months. On the flip side, should they be alone in a small town with one moneylender, that's going to double the interest rate for the same loan - 50% over four months. If, on the other hand, they're a well known party looking to borrow money for some specialized gear, they might be able to get away with as low as 5% in four months.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about the high level factors, let me try to give you my take on economic theories (but take for granted that economy is not an exact science, else if all the theories economists have would be correct, they would get their income by speculating in the stock exchange, not writing book of economy where they explain why their past forecasts were wrong).

Each item, good or service, as a price. The price in a free market is determined, according to the accepted theories, by meeting the demand and offer: If I have 100 bottles of water and only 1 person wants to buy 1 bottle, I can ask a lower price, while if I have the same 100 bottles of water but I have 1000 persons seeking a beverage I can ask a much higher price. If you have ever been to a concert or an airport, you now understand why you pay so much for so few.

Interest rate is the price one pay to get money from those who have money. When there is a high demand of money (the economy is growing, companies are investing, etc.) the rates go up. When the demand of money is low (recession, no investments), the rates go down.

This is the layman version. Therefore try to determine what your local economy is doing, and adjust the interests accordingly.